# why document.write not showing the result

Tags: javascript, operators, document.write

I'm learning js, by my script i'm trying to 2 + 10 = 12 using plus operator.
But result not showing on my editor preview. Where i'm going wrong?

**JS:**

```
ver two = 2;
ver ten = 10;
ver result = two + ten;

document.write("Two Plus Ten = ")
document.write(result)
```

I'm expecting your suggestion, where is the mistake on this js. I'm trying to learn so please don't suggest another JS. 

Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/Lnaj4zdb/

Comment: [v**a**r. NOT `ver`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/Lnaj4zdb/1/)

Comment: Before coming here again, please learn how to look in the debug console where simple script errors will be shown to you and you can probably find and fix simple mistakes like this.  If you see the error in the console, but are not sure how to fix it, THEN you can post here with all the info you have collected and ask for help.

Comment: @jfriend00  Thanks, i forgot

Answer (score 1):

Because of this

```
ver two = 2;
ver ten = 10;
ver result = two + ten;
```

it should be `var` not `ver`

```
var two = 2;
var ten = 10;
var result = two + ten;
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/Lnaj4zdb/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Typo it should be `var` not `ver`

```
var two = 2;
var ten = 10;
var result = two + ten;
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, now i understand.